# SQLTimeoutException in play-slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I'm using play-slick with slick 3.0.0 in this way:

I got a connection by

```
val conn = db.createSession.conn
```

then got statement:

```
val statement = conn.prepareStatement(querySQL)
```

and return ResultSet:

```
Future{statement.executeQuery()}
```

But I got a problem: I tried to use this query about **50** times, then, I got the exception:

> SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.

I know this may caused by connections are not closed and  **I didn't close the connection or session in my code manually.**

I want to know:

- Will connection create by my way close and return to connection pool automatically?
- Was my situation caused by connection didn't release?
- How to close a connection manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: It would most helpful, if you post your full code (including your call that is performed 50 times)

> Will connection create by my way close and return to connection pool automatically?

No. Even though Java 7 (and up) provides the so called try-with-resources (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html ) to auto-close your resource. ,AFAIK, this mechanism is not available in Scala (please correct me somebody, if this is not true). 
Still, Scala provides the LOAN-Pattern ( see https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan , especially `using` ) which provides a FP way of closing resources finally.

> Was my situation caused by connection didn't release?

As long as you don't provide your full code, it is only a guess. Yes, not closing connections make the connection pool exceed, thus that no new connections are available eventually.

> How to close a connection manually?

`connection.close()`